# JavaScript won't check for null condition

Tags: javascript, null

So, I'm writing a code in JS that asks the user for their name and prints the greeting in the console. If a user clicks 'cancel' that is the value stored in the variable 'name' is null, the code should return "You didn't give a name". Instead, it prints "Hello, null" which is weird.

```js
var name = prompt("what's your name?");

function hello(name) {
  if ((name == null) || (name == "")) {
    console.log('you didn\'t give me a name')
  } else {
    console.log(`Hello, ${name}!`);
  }
}

hello(name);
```

expected: "you didn't give a name"

result  : "Hello, null"

Comment: In what kind of environment are you running this? The code outputs your expected result in Chrome. https://codesandbox.io/s/javascript-forked-gukh5?file=/index.js

Comment: The way to debug this kinda of thing is with `console.log(typeof(name))`.

Comment: I tried this in chrome console and it didn't work as I expected it to

Comment: I also tried console.log(typeof(name)) and it showed me that the name was null but still the code didn't work as it was supposed to

Answer (score 2):

```
var name = null;

function hello(name){
    if ((name == 'null') ||( name == "")){
        console.log('you didn\'t give me a name')
    }
    else {
        console.log(`Hello, ${name}!`);
    }  
}

hello(name);
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried to do the same thing but it didn't use to work. Now it does...

Answer (score 1):

name is a string here, whose value is "null" and not null, If you fix the check to name == "null", you should get your desired result

Comment: Thanks! That actually was the first thing I tried but somehow that used to make no difference. Now it magically does. I might be tripping...